# Adding a line break as separator

Tags: php

I have a function that uses comma as separator in breaking name/email pairs from a long string. I would like to modify this function to be able to detect if instead of a comma a line break is used. Here's the function that needs to be modified:

```
$str = '"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, abc@gmail.com';
$pairs = explode( ",", $str );
foreach( $pairs as $pair ) {
  if( strpos($pair, '<') ) {
    $output = explode( "<", $pair );
    $output['0'] = trim( str_replace( "\"", "", $output['0'] ) );
    $output['1'] = trim( rtrim( $output['1'], ">" ) );
  } else {
    $output = array();
    $output['0'] = '';
    $output['1'] = $pair;
  }
  print_r($output); // Save it to database here
}
```

I found a post suggesting using a file() fnction but I am not sure how to combine those two together.

```
$str = '"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, abc@gmail.com';
$pairs = file($str, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, convert to line breaks then check if exists

```
$str=nl2br($str);
if (strpos($str,'<br />')!==false){
$pairs = array_filter(explode( "<br />", $str ));
}
```

Or alternatively, you can break apart on spaces which should catch the line breaks

```
if (strpos($str,' ')!==false){
$pairs = array_filter(explode( " ", $str ));
}
```

Note; I added the array_filter because it will remove empty values for you.
Also, I would suggest using the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL from here http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php before adding to your database.

Comment: Yes, I plan to first display all the values to user and then after submit, still validate email. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A true linebreak in php is written as `"\n"`. Simply use

```
$pairs = explode( "\n", $str );
```

Note that the `\` changes behavior for the `n`, thus making it a line break. `"\n"` gives a nice line while `"\\n"` gives `\n` as output.